# installing pygame on python3.5 osx

Tags: python, macos, pygame

Im trying to install pygame

```
pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

getting this error:

```
Collecting hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
Cloning hg http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame to     /var/folders/vl/g_3vs3xj2clcnyc58spzmjq00000gn/T/pip-7f5mltpu-build
Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hg' while executing   command hg clone --noupdate -q http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame 
/var/folders/vl/g_3vs3xj2clcnyc58spzmjq00000gn/T/pip-7f5mltpu-build
Cannot find command 'hg'
```

or

```
brew install pygame
```

error:

```
Error: Failed to download resource "pygame"
Failure while executing: /usr/local/opt/mercurial/bin/hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame /Library/Caches/Homebrew/pygame--hg
```

anyone successfully installed pygame on osx with python 3.5?

Comment: your question is not correct as the problem is mercurial on your machine and not pygame install.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be missing mercurial
you can simply run

```
brew install mercurial
```

which will install hg
and than you will be able to install from mercurial source

also in order to install pygame you need to install sdl

```
brew install sdl
```

Comment: OK, when running /usr/local/opt/mercurial/bin/hg without any paramters what do you get?

Comment: -bash: /usr/local/opt/mercurial/bin/hg: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: weird, it seems that the system python is corrupted. can you run which python (not in virtualenv) and python -V

Comment: python -V –  Python 2.7.10

Comment: python3 -V Python 3.5.0

Comment: /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97100/discussion-between-simplesystems-and-srgrn).

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way:

```
pip3 install pygame
```